# Trying to hook up an external monitor to netbook

Tags: 12.04, resolution, external-monitor, vga, xrandr

When I plug the external monitor up to my netbook it isn't found. I restart with them connected and it displays on the external monitor, but in the wrong resolution, shifted ~100 pixels to the right, and in a slightly brownish hue. I've tried using xrandr but it always gives me an error stating that

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

The netbook's original monitor has the resolution of 1024x600 (16:9) and the monitor has 1600x900(16:9), but when I restart with them connected the default resolution of the netbook itself changes to 1024x768(4:3).

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I have an integrated Intel chip if that helps.

Comment: Congrats on getting it solved, can you add that as an answer? - a step by step guide will help others :)

Answer (score 2):

OP answered:

> Ended up using arandr, a gui for xrandr, and almost fixed it, the rest is likely a driver problem.